# Do we have to install active admin before using arctic admin theme?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to add ArcticAdmin. I've tried the steps below:

1. Gem file >> gem 'arctic_admin'
2. bundle install

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As **ArticAdmin** provides the simple theme to Active Admin. You first need to install the active admin before using this.

**Steps:-**

1. Install `active_admin`
2. Follow the[artic admin installation steps](https://github.com/cprodhomme/arctic_admin#installation)

Comment: Helped me a lot.